# How to assign value to array in Arduino?

Tags: multidimensional-array, arduino

I have below code in Arduino:

```
const byte L[] = {
  B01100000,
  B01100000,
  B01100000,
  B01100000,
  B01100000,
  B01100000,
  B01111110,
  B01111110
};

const byte K[] = {B00100010,
  B00100100,
  B00101000,
  B00110000,
  B00110000,
  B00101000,
  B00100100,
  B00100010};
const byte LK[][8]={L,K};
```

I will get an error `array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer` on the last line. I wonder how to assign value to two dimensional in Arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a array of pointers to achieve this:

```
const byte* LK[2] = {L, K}
```